# Default .htaccess file for WordPress?

Tags: htaccess

My `.htaccess` files are intercepting WordPress' `.htaccess` file.

Which modules and which settings (specified by `.htaccess`) are required for WordPress to work? In other words, where can I find WordPress' default `.htaccess` file?

Comment: There is the WordPress codex article about [`htaccess`](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess) files.

Answer (score 36):

Here is the default code for that file.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

you can check it here for default htaccess file.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks.

Thanks. I hope it helps little.

Comment: Please, see the chat [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/4000365#4000365) about this.

Comment: !!!  The answer is obsolete. Use the new  :https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/250918/33667

Comment: Updated link: https://wordpress.org/support/article/using-permalinks/

Answer (score 7):

WordPress does not contain `.htaccess` in file form.

The rules are written into file by [`save_mod_rewrite_rules()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/save_mod_rewrite_rules) function and are generated by `$wp_rewrite->mod_rewrite_rules()`.

Note that multisite installation has different (more complex) rules and seems to be handled differently.

Comment: +1 for the right direction. Please, review whether I understood the issue right with my answer. I think the central thing is just to use the Rewrite_WP API, not to reinvent the wheel with personal .htaccess -files.

Answer (score 4):

## Use the latest version of default `.htaccess`

**https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/**.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Freenode's #wordpress to find the appropriate documentation, usually in the `/topic`. There I found the key `Class WP_Rewrite` [here](http://phpdoc.wordpress.org/trunk/), the official wordpress.org is at the best misleading and marketing. Anyway, do not mix Apache's rewrite rules with WP's rewrite rules although the naming of WP is probably from Apache's equivalent.

The WP_Rewrite API states

> You can add rules to trigger your page view and processing using this component. The full functionality of a front controller does not exist, **meaning you can't define how the template files load based on the rewrite rules.**

so you must use the API to do the changes, not fully sure what it means but I think it means you cannot trust in your hard-coded .htaccess -files -- things may change even with different WD -versions! So use the API.

> intercepting

The code [here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.2/wp-admin/includes/misc.php) has some conditions if the .htaccess -file exists -- not 100% of their inferences because not well-documented and cannot understand the naming there but the central message is probably that the safe way to maintain the rewrite rules is to use the WP_Rewrite API, WP may change in the future.

For example, a simple Apache-rewrite `RewriteRule ^hello$ Layouts/hello.html [NC,L]` is apparently something like `add_rewrite("^hello$", "Layouts/hello.html")`, haven't tested but tried to follow the API below:

```
add_rewrite_rule (line 19)
Add a straight rewrite rule.

see: WP_Rewrite::add_rule() for long description.
since: 2.1.0
void add_rewrite_rule (string $regex, string $redirect, [string $after = 'bottom'])
string $regex: Regular Expression to match request against.
string $redirect: Page to redirect to.
string $after: Optional, default is 'bottom'. Where to add rule, can also be 'top'.
```

**Related**

1. http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule
2. http://pmg.co/a-mostly-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-rewrite-api
3. Thanks to toscho for assisting [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4314895#4314895), some small-talk in chat.

Comment: I am quite sure I have misunderstood here something, please, review this chat [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/4000298#4000298). Did it intercept because my blog was on root -level meaning something like www.hello.com/blog/?